# How to convert from jpg to bitmap with only black and white

Tags: image-processing, bitmap, imagemagick

I am having a jpeg file, for which I want to find the color of each pixel. So I thought to convert the jpg to bitmap first, then apply threshold onto the bitmap file[ to convert each pixel either black or white], and then write a C code, that eliminates first 54 bytes of the file for the header, and after that get bytes in chunk of three [RGB] and check for the colour.

Now, how do I convert from jpeg to bitmap, and how do I apply threshold to it using imagemagick? What commands shall I use?

Also, do I stand corrected on the processing the pixels part for my C code? i.e. I will reject the first 54 bytes from the bitmap FILE and then get the bytes , three at a time, and store each differently. and do the same for all other 'chunk of three bytes'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert <jpgfile> -threshold xx% <bmpfile>
```

As for the BMP header info, I don't think it is as simple as that... I'm weak in C, but take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format for your header info.  It says that it is variable in length.  I would suggest searching google for example code on reading BMP files in C.

Or ==> "[read bitmap file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure)"

Comment: @lamiuru When I do the above convert statement, my pixels in bmp wil have either 255,255,255 or 0,0,0 right?

Comment: @lamiuru That is, they'll all either be, black or white? And if I could take out the correct header apart, and then perform, extraction of rgb, I shall get [0,0,0] or [255,255,255]?

Comment: Correct.  This will produce a 2 color black and white image.  NOT greyscale.

Comment: And by 2 color I mean only 2 colors are in the file... not a color depth of 1-bit.

Comment: @lamiuru I am not sure if I follow you. What is the difference between greyscale and 2 colors black and white image? What do I do, so that my final image, abc.bmp have each pixel value as either 000 for white , or 255 255 255 for black?
And what is the color depth of 1-bit?

Comment: If you have a 1-bit image, it can only be 2 colors.  Even though you are working with a 24-bit image, this will produce a purely black and white image.  From what you have said, this is what you want.  Not a greyscale image that could contain (1,1,1)-(254,254,254)..  "-threshold" will produce what you have asked for, (0,0,0) or (255,255,255) and nothing in between.

Comment: @lamiuru Yeah, what i want is that my jpg, when turned to bmp, each pixel should be white or black, i.e. 000 or 255 255 255, nothing in between. `convert <jpgfile> -threshold xx% <bmpfile>` will do that for me right?