# How to convert IplImage opencv to byte array (bmp format) C++?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

Client recieve image ([Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx)) over network (Windows Forms C#). Server send image as byte array (bmp format). How to convert IplImage opencv to byte array (bmp format) C++? Without saving to a file (performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use opencv function [**imencode**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imencode)

Description

```
bool imencode(const string& ext, const Mat& img, vector<uchar>& buf, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>())
```

Example

```
vector<uchar> buf;
Mat matImage = iplImage;
imencode(".bmp", matImage, buf);
size = buf.size();
copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you just want to save the file or if you want to code a structure for it.

```
cvSaveImage("foo.bmp",img); // img is your IplImage
```

[read bitmap file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure) describes how you can define a nice structure for your bmp file if you want to send it from the server (it's C but if you want, I guess you can adapt it)