# Confusion regarding pointer size

Tags: c, windows, pointers, 64-bit

This may be a noob question ..but this is really confusing me..

Below is some sample code

```
void main() {

    int a = 300;
    char *ptr = &a;
    int *intptr = &a;

    printf("%d\n %d\n", *ptr, *intptr);

}
```

**output:**
44
300

As per my understanding,why dereferencing `*ptr` prints 44 is due to the fact that char pointer is one byte and so it reads only 8 bits from the address  of int...

But this [question:What is the size of a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer) states `Regardless of what data type they are pointing to, they have fixed size`

Am i missing some thing.Why dereferencing char pointer prints 44,if pointer size is same ?

Comment: Nothing in your code above deals with pointer sizes.

Comment: Incidentally 256 + 44 = 300

Comment: The size of a pointer is not the same as the size of what it points **to**. Here `char *ptr` says that `*ptr` is a `char`. The result is complicated by the fact that it really is not pointing to a `char`.

Comment: In your example, your pointers not only have the same size, but they have the same value.  But when dereferenced, one of them loads a single byte while the other loads an integer.  Why is that confusing?  `sizeof(ptr)` is the pointer size.  `sizeof(*ptr)` is the size of the data type it points to.

Comment: `Why is that confusing? ` I missed the fact that during dereferencing data type comes into picture

Comment: `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     char *ptr = &a;
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object pointers (e.g. pointers to anything besides a function) are typically the same size on most systems you're likely to come across, however there's no guarantee of that.  That being said, even though the *pointers* may be the same size, the *types* that they point to are not.

For example, on a 64-bit Windows system, pointers are typically 8 bytes in size.  In your example you have `char *` and an `int *` which are most likely both 8 bytes.  The difference here is that dereferencing a `char *` will read/write 1 byte while dereferenceing an `int *` will read/write 4 bytes (assuming an `int` is 32 bit).

Assuming little endian byte ordering, `a` looks like this in memory:

```
  ------------------
a | 44 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
  ------------------
```

Both `ptr` and `intptr` contain the address of `a`.  When dereferencing `ptr`, which is of type `char *`, it only looks at the first byte.  In contrast, when dereferencing `intptr`, which is of type `int *`, it looks at all 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks,so pointer irrespective of its data type might be of same size ,but when dereferencing,it depends on data type..Am i correct

Comment: @TheGameiswar Not necessarily 8 bytes (not 8 bits).  It could be 4 bytes if you're on a 32-bit system.  The standard doesn't guarantee that all pointers are the same size, but in practice they tend to be.  But yes, the main difference is when the pointer is dereferenced.  The number of bytes read/written depend on the type.

Comment: @dbush Great Answer, But your picture representation of memory of variable 'a' is little confusing to noobs like me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your code is not valid C and it also invokes undefined behavior, so anything can happen. If your compiler didn't show you any diagnostic messages, you need to uninstall it and get a working one instead. You have the following bugs:

- `void main()` will only work on freestanding implementations that specifically allow this form of main.
- `char *ptr = &a;` is not a valid form of assignment in C. The pointers are not compatible<sup>(1)</sup>.
- Printing a character with the `%d` format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

After fixing these bugs, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int a = 300;
  char *ptr = (char*)&a;
  int *intptr = &a;

  printf("%d\n %d\n", (int)*ptr, *intptr);
}
```

None of this prints the size of a pointer. You print the contents of the first byte in the `int a`, which you translate to a `char`, which may or may not be signed and possibly give an incorrect result (this part is endianess-dependent). And then you print the contents of the whole `int a`.

What you seem to want is to print the size of the pointers themselves:

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof ptr, sizeof intptr);
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> C11 6.5.16.1 emphasis mine:

> **Constraints**
>   One of the following shall hold:
>   /--/
>   - the **left operand has** atomic, qualified, or unqualified **pointer type, and** (considering
>   the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) **both operands are
>   pointers to** qualified or unqualified versions of **compatible types**, and the type pointed
>   to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Comment: In C, a pointer to any object may be converted to a pointer to a character type and back.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not implicitly, it would violate the constraints of simple assignment, since the pointers are not compatible. C11 6.5.16.1: `the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;`

Comment: Printing a `char` value with `%d` is fine due to integer promotion. (Unless you are using a bizarre C implementation where `int` and `char` have been distorted to be the same size, as has been discussed elsewhere on Stack Overflow.) I do not think it is best to hammer the OP with C violations first rather than helping them understand what they have observed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil For a normal VA function, yes then the default argument promotion apply. But the (dysfunctional) printf family of functions explicitly labels it UB, C11 7.21.6.1/9 `If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.`. As for hammering the OP, they are obviously compiling their code with some random crap they found in a packet of corn flakes. We need to point out that they need to use a compliant compiler instead of a broken one.

Comment: I think that is an excessive interpretation. For example, 6.5.2.2 4 says “each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.” So “value of the corresponding argument” here must mean the value of the argument after the promotions and conversions specified in this clause, as assigning the value before those would not be sensible (or always possible). Yet they did not write “value of the corresponding argument after the promotions and conversions specified in this clause.” So the standard may use “arguments” to mean the arguments after promotion and conversion.

Comment: And they do not have to be first. The way things are said to a person affects how they interpret them. Explaining first, and giving them a model by which they can understand the behavior, is a better introduction to what you have to say than saying they are doing things wrong. They have indicated what information they want by asking a question, so give them that information first, when possible.

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
printf("%d\n %d\n", *ptr, *intptr);
```

there are outputted not the pointers themselves but the data they point to.

For example `300` can be represented like `256 + 44`. So `44` can be stored in one byte while 256 can be stored in another byte.  And this expression `*ptr` gives the value 44 stored in the byte pointed to by the pointer `ptr`.

On the other hand the pointer `intptr` points to the whole object of the type `int` and the expression `*intptr`  gives the value 300.

If you want to output the addresses stored in the pointers you should write

```
printf("%p\n %p\n", ( void * )ptr, ( void * )intptr);
```

To output sizes of the pointers you could write

```
printf("%zu\n %zu\n", sizeof( ptr ), sizeof( intptr ));
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also in this declaration you should use an explicit casting

```
char *ptr = ( char * )&a;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 300;
    char *ptr = ( char * )&a;
    int *intptr = &a;

    printf( "*ptr = %d, *intptr = %d\n", *ptr, *intptr );
    printf( "ptr = %p, intptr = %p\n", ( void * )ptr, ( void * )intptr );
    printf( "sizeof( ptr ) = %zu, sizeof( intptr ) = %zu\n", 
        sizeof( ptr ), sizeof( intptr ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
*ptr = 44, *intptr = 300
ptr = 0x7ffe5972613c, intptr = 0x7ffe5972613c
sizeof( ptr ) = 8, sizeof( intptr ) = 8
```

Comment: All that  is left is to print the size of `char, int`.

Answer (score 2):

You introduce undefined behaviour if you cast a pointer to an object to a different type than that of the object AND access it then through this pointer.

Statement `int a = 300` introduces an object of type `int`, `char* ptr = &a` introduces a pointer to an object of type `char` but let it point to an object of type `int`. This per se is not a problem, but dereferencing this pointer then through `*ptr` is undefined behaviour. And this does not have something to do with the `printf` - a statement like `char x = *ptr` would be UB, too. However, a statement like `int x = *((int *)ptr)` would be OK, as the ptr is casted back to the original type of the object it points to.

Concerning the sizes of pointers: The size of a pointer (i.e. the value necessary for storing a memory address to which the pointer points to) is fixed size; it's usually 4 bytes on a 32 bit system and 8 bytes on a 64 bit system. The size necessary for representing a memory address has nothing to do with the size of the object that resides at the respecite memory address to which the pointer points to.

The following example demonstrates this behaviour:

```
int main() {

    int a = 300;
    void *ptr = &a;
    int *intptr = &a;

    printf("%d %d\n", *((int*)ptr), *intptr);   
}
```

Output:

```
300 300
```

Comment: Accessing an object through a character pointer is defined in C.

Comment: The OP doesn't _cast_ anywhere, cast != conversion. Which is why their code `char* ptr = &a` is not valid C. That being said, using character pointers to other types do _not_ invoke UB, there's an explicit exception from the strict aliasing rule. Basically half of this answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is false. Any pointer to an object may be converted to a character type and access the bytes of the object through the character type. As Lundin points out, the assignment `char *ptr = &a` is not strictly conforming C, but `char *ptr = (char *) &a` fixes that.

Comment: "You introduce undefined behaviour if you cast a pointer to an object to a different type than that of the object AND access it then through this pointer." is just plain wrong for character types. You can access anything from a character pointer, but you cannot do the opposite, ie access a chunk of characters through another pointer type. See the FAQ [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, on a little endian architecture, the LSB would appear first in memory, thus to store 300, memory looks like

```
44 , 1 , 0 , 0  (for a size 4 int)
```

The

```
printf("%d\n %d\n", *ptr, *intptr);
```

doesn't print the pointer sizes (which are likely the same), it prints the *dereferenced* pointers, values of one byte, a char, then the int value.

To print the pointer sizes

```
printf ("%zu\n%zu\n", sizeof(ptr), sizeof(intptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned int
trans(unsigned char c){
  if ('0' <=c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
  if ('A' <=c && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 0x0A;
  if ('a' <=c && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 0x0A;
  return 0;
}

uint16_t
hex_to_uint16(const char* s) {
  char *p = (char*) s;
  uint16_t v = 0;
  while (*p) {
    if (p > s) v = v << 4;
    v += trans(*p);
    p++;
  }
  return v;
}

int main (void)
{

  int n = 1;
    // little endian if true
    if(*(char *)&n == 1) {printf("little\n");}

  int a = 300;
  char *ptr =  (char*)&a;
  int *intptr = &a;

    printf("charSize:%zu intSize:%zu\n", sizeof (char), sizeof (int));
    printf("PcharSize:%zu PintSize:%zu\n", sizeof (ptr), sizeof (intptr));


  //printf("Hex: %x, Decimal: %d\n", 0x2c, (int)0x2c ); 

  //printf("int: %d\n", hex_to_uint16("2c"));
    //printf("300H: %x\n", (a));


    printf("PcharAddr: %p\nPintAddr: %p\n", ptr, intptr);


  printf("int: %d\n", *intptr);


  printf("LSB  |     |     |  MSB|\n");
  printf("  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |\n");
  printf("------------------------\n");
  printf("Dec\n");
  printf(" %d     %d     %d     %d\n", *(ptr), *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3));
  printf("Hex\n");
  printf(" %x     %x     %x     %x\n", *(ptr), *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3));



    printf("To Big Endian:\n%.2x%x%x%x\n", (uint8_t)*(ptr+3), (uint8_t)*(ptr+2), (uint8_t)*(ptr+1), (uint8_t)*(ptr));

  ///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275955/convert-little-endian-to-big-endian
    /*
     * chux aswer
    uint32_t num = 300;
    uint8_t b[4];

    b[0] = (uint8_t) (num >>  0u);
    b[1] = (uint8_t) (num >>  8u);
    b[2] = (uint8_t) (num >> 16u);
    b[3] = (uint8_t) (num >> 24u);

  printf("%x%x%x%x\n", b[3], b[2], b[1], b[0]);

  */

    return 0;
}
```

***Compile, Run***

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra te.c -o te && ./te
```

Answer (score -1):

no, no, no

> As per my understanding,why dereferencing *ptr prints 44 is due to the fact that char pointer is one byte and so it reads only 8 bits from the address of int...

char is one byte, not char pointer. If you want to print pointer you should

```
printf("%p\n %p\n", ptr, intptr);
```

Comment: @babon: And cast them to `void *` or `const void *`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Absolutely :)

Comment: Yes, I agree. The code above in fact wasn't intended to print real flat address, but only show that it is the same value, regardless pointer type ;)