# Efficient big endian byte array to native integer conversion in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, arm

1) Are there any compiler builtins, or assembly instructions for x86, ARM or another architecture that will take a big endian byte array (2 bytes -> uint16_t, 4 bytes -> uint32_t, 8 bytes -> uint64_t) and convert it to an unsigned integer of native endianness (big, little, mixed) .

2) Are there also any builtins or instructions to perform the inverse conversion (integer to big endian byte array).

Naive native C functions would be:

```
static inline void put_be16(uint8_t a[static sizeof(uint16_t)], uint16_t val)
{
    a[0] = (val >> 8) & 0xff;
    a[1] = val & 0xff;
}

static inline uint16_t get_be16(uint8_t const a[static sizeof(uint16_t)])
{
    return (a[0] << 8) | a[1];
}
```

These are for reading unsigned integers from inbound network packets, and encoding unsigned integers for use in outbound network packets.

Solutions must prevent, or mitigate unaligned memory accesses.

Edit: And looking to be efficient, so something that operates directly on the input/output buffer is what I'm really looking for.

Comment: Yes, most compilers have builtins.  There are some headers that try to portably expose efficient versions across compilers, e.g. `be16toh()` on systems that have that function.

Comment: `ntohs` and `htons` functions be of use to you?

Comment: Regarding `ntohs` and `htons`, In this case no. I'm trying to avoid the memcpy that'd be required for proper aligned access, which is a prerequisite of those functions/macros.  There's also a pedantic corner of the internet which argues use of those functions/macros is wrong in the majority of cases when dealing with network packets.

Comment: Same issue with `be16toh()` unless it's guaranteed to produce aligned accesses. This is why the question is explicit about the input being a  byte array for the 'from network' solution, and a byte array for the output of the 'to network' solution.

Comment: Those functions do not take pointers, they don't produce any accesses themselves. It's your job to load and store the input and output which is where alignment comes into play.

Comment: Which involves a memcpy which as I stated, I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No it does not necessarily involve memcpy - you do not need to copy the whole array, you just need to load and store the items one by one. Also, that's no fault of the functions.

Comment: Ha, quite. Fixed.

Comment: Note: `return (a[0] << 8) | a[1];` potentially is technically UB on 16-bit `int` machines.  `return ((unsigned) a[0] << 8) | a[1];` is better.

Comment: @Jester could you provide some example code that's architecture agnostic, I'm not sure I understand what you mean there.

Comment: @chux Could you explain why it's UB, not doubting, just interested to know.

Comment: `128 << 8` shifts into the sign bit: "The result of E1 << E2 is .... If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1  2^E2 is
representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: But isn't E1 an unsigned type in this instance being uint8_t?

Comment: Ugh, integer promotion is something I can never remember the rules for.   I'd say `return ((uint16_t)a[0] << 8) | a[1];` was actually the correct code, but the current code does work as posted.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem, I thought you had a massive array of values to byte swap but apparently your array is only the size of a single item. Anyway, for the `get_xx` versions both gcc and clang seem to recognize the intent and optimize it to unaligned load and appropriate byte swapping if available on the architecture.

Comment: That also holds for the `put_xx` except for 32 bit ARM gcc for which I couldn't make it work.

Comment: However `val = htonl(val); memcpy(a, &val, 4);` does work there as well. It produces a `rev` + `str` pair.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell " but the current code does work as posted." --> if your tests only include a 32-bit `int/unsigned`, then yes it works.  Even with 16-bit `int`, your code may "work", yet still rely on UB.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell Answers to Q1 & Q2 are both yes.  "And looking to be efficient" is a worthy goal, yet true efficiency comes with looking at the larger picture, not this narrow micro-optimization goal.  To really get speed performance, post your best true code with a timing assessment and ask for how to improve its speed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the C side, I think this has been asked before. I found this with a quick search:
[Convert Little Endian to Big Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275955/convert-little-endian-to-big-endian/19276193)

You can use htonl(), htons(), and related, which will convert to and from a known big-endian format. You can also use a union to extract the individual bytes from an int or long, etc., as in:

```
union extract_byte_val {
    long long_val;
    uint8_t bytes_val[sizeof(long)];
}
```

For example:

```
long x = 128;
union extract_byte_val eb;
eb.long_val = htonl(x);
```

eb.bytes_val is now {0, 0, 0, 128}, since eb.long_val is bug-endian.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use unions to parse network packets like that.  On systems where unaligned accesses are fatal, you'll kill your program.  Happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: and this isn't a duplicate of the question you posted.

Comment: I think the compiler would re-align things, but that would slow things down, so I see your point. I can't think of any modern CPUs that handle non-aligned integers, they all assume that you can manage to get the data aligned into memory somehow first.

Comment: I thought the answers to the question might give you some ideas.

Comment: Note that `htonl()` is not a C standard function.  If it takes an `int/unsigned/uin32_t/uint16_t/...` is implementation defined.  I'd expect most implementations to takes some unsigned argument, yet the width can vary.  `htonl32()` and the like are more predictable.

Comment: Unfortunately even modern compilers aren't that smart.  There's only a limited subset of operations/builtin functions which guarantee aligned accesses, of which `memcpy` is one.  That's why casting a union over a buffer containing a network packet to extract fields at fixed offsets, if those fields are > 8bits is bad practice if you're targeting an unknown architecture.

Comment: @chux `htonl()` is defined by POSIX to take a 32 bit unsigned int.

Comment: @Shawn Limiting ourselves to POSIX is not clearly required here.

Comment: @chux The only non-POSIX conforming OS anyone is likely to use is Windows, and Winsock also specifies that it works with unsigned 32 bit ints. Pretending it might work with a different size of integer is pretty silly these days.

Comment: @Shawn Billions of processors/year are embedded ones.  Large number of those do not have any OS.  C is designed to be highly portable across old and new/novel  architectures.  `htonl()` inheritable implies `host-to-network-long` yet many `long` are now 64-bit.  OP is looking for high portability given the "big, little, mixed".  [htobe16(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htobe16) are a better less ambiguous function set design.

Comment: @chux Name an embedded system that provides a `htonl()` that doesn't work on 32 bit values. I'll be honestly very surprised if such a thing exists in modern times. Plus does OP say anything about working in an embedded environment? (I used to feel the same way about `htonl()` until it was pointed out to me that it's standardized to 32 bit values. At that point, why be pedantic when you can be practical?)

Comment: The issue with `htonl()` is more about needing to copy the bytes to an intermediary location, so it's more to do with the efficiency that the portability.

Comment: @Shawn Using `htonl()` and friends  1) lack a 64-bit version. 2) lack a clear naming to wider types.  3) refer to network order rather than clearly "big endian" and explicitly requested by OP. OP did not mention an OS in the question either.  Using `htobeNN()` is not a pedantic concern, but a clear future thinking approach as many newer functions tend to use `NN` especially anything in communication.  There is a good practical reason why *nix rolled these out for clarity.

Comment: @Shawn Give you the option for last word, else we should move this to chat.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell: you can use `memcpy` to express an unaligned load into an object.  It will optimize away on machines that support unaligned loads, but unfortunately can compile horribly (an actual call to the libc function) on ISAs like MIPS.  In GNU C, you can use `typedef int unaligned_int __attribute((aligned(1)))` or something; see [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/57676035).  So only non-GNU-compatible compilers would need the memcpy fallback.

Comment: @Shawn: “You cannot show me a platform this does not work on, so I will assume it works” is not a valid engineering process. It makes things blow up and fall down. Engineering proceeds by constructing proper designs from given specifications, not from hopes that not only are there no counterexamples at hand now but that none exist at all and will not exist in the future. Knowingly designing out of specification is malpractice.

Comment: "That's why casting a union over a buffer containing a network packet to extract fields at fixed offsets, if those fields are > 8bits is bad practice" - I'd consider casting in general to be bad practice, so it didn't occur to me you'd think of doing that.

Comment: I take it you can't control how the input data is aligned. I suppose the best you could do in that case is split your integer in two, based on the lower 4 bits of the address - extract the top 1-3 bytes of one, lower 3-1 bytes of the other, mask, shift, and combine the resulting integers into the one you want. I don't know how much time you'd save over the complexity of something like that, but that's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like that

```
int swap_int(unsigned char *byte) {
unsigned char temp;

temp = byte[3];
byte[3] = byte[0];
byte[0] = temp;
temp = byte[2];
byte[2] = byte[1];
byte[1] = temp;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only works for big to little endian conversion.

Comment: (and vice versa).

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell: You can detect whether your implementation is big or little endian using portable C (which should optimize away):  access the bytes of a `const uint16_t testval = 0x0001`.  But I wouldn't count on optimizers turning this C back into a `bswap` or `movbe` instruction.  If you care about performance across compilers, you may need to use intrinsics.