# Converting from decimal to binary in the right order

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm a complete noob in c++ and we had to do a programm in school that calculates the cross sum of a number and then convert this number to a binary number.

The problem I have now is that the binary number is in reverse order.
I want to add the digits into an array and then cout the array from right to left, but I do not have any Idea how to do it. :/

Could someone explain / show me how to do it?

And I am using the do while loops because that was the requirement for the task...

```
int main()
{
    int digit, sum = 0, rem;

    cout<<"Enter a positive digit" << endl;
    cin >>  digit;

    do {
        sum= sum + (digit%10); 
        digit /= 10;
    }
    while (digit!= 0);

    cout <<"Cross sum" << sum << endl; 

    do {
        rem = sum % 2;
        sum /= 2;
        cout << "Decimal in Binary: " << rem << endl;
    }
    while(sum>0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275955/convert-little-endian-to-big-endian/19276193

Comment: `digit` is already binary. There is no decimal here. Any decimal to binary conversion is already carried out by `cin >> digit;`.

Comment: @user207421 Given a `sum` of 6, the OP wants an output of "110", but is getting "011" - that is what he means by "binary".

Comment: Also you print the binary number on the wrong order. One way to do it is to use code start's recursive suggestion below.

Comment: @JonasByström - What do you mean "**also** you print the binary number [in] the wrong order"?  The fact the binary number is coming out in the wrong order is the *whole point* of the OP's question.

Comment: @MartinBonner: also, as in apart from the unnecessary "decimal conversion" talked about above.

Comment: OP: Start with pen and paper. "If this, than that..." and draw lines. it *will* help. Randomlly throwing in programming stuff doesn't help. Figure out the logic flow **you** want.

Answer (score 0):

This function will print decimal to binary in right order:

```
void decToBin(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    decToBin(n / 2);
    cout << n % 2;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use right shift `operator>>` and the binary AND `operator &`.  Many times more efficient than remainder and division (however compiles may recognize the pattern and make the optimization).