# I am unable to load a .BMP image

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, bmp

I am new to opengl. I am trying to load an image using opengl. But I am unable to do so. It gives me this error:

```
*** Error in `./lena': double free or corruption (top) : 0x0000000001353070 ***
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. My code has been given below. Actually it is not my code. I have seen it in another post in Stack Overflow by someone named Ollo.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER
{
    int bfType;  //specifies the file type
    long long bfSize;  //specifies the size in bytes of the bitmap file
    int bfReserved1;  //reserved; must be 0
    int bfReserved2;  //reserved; must be 0
    long long bOffBits;  //species the offset in bytes from the bitmapfileheader to the bitmap bits
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    long long biSize;  //specifies the number of bytes required by the struct
    long long biWidth;  //specifies width in pixels
    long long biHeight;  //species height in pixels
    int biPlanes; //specifies the number of color planes, must be 1
    int biBitCount; //specifies the number of bit per pixel
    long long biCompression;//spcifies the type of compression
    long long biSizeImage;  //size of image in bytes
    long long biXPelsPerMeter;  //number of pixels per meter in x axis
    long long biYPelsPerMeter;  //number of pixels per meter in y axis
    long long biClrUsed;  //number of colors used by th ebitmap
    long long biClrImportant;  //number of colors that are important
};

int main(void){
    FILE *filePtr;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER *bitmapInfoHeader = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    unsigned char *bitmapImage;  //store image data
    int imageIdx=0;  //image index counter
    unsigned char tempRGB;  //our swap variable

    filePtr = fopen("lena.bmp","rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
        cout << "ERROR!!! 1" << endl;
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,filePtr);

    fread(bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,filePtr); // small edit. forgot to add the closing bracket at sizeof

    //move file point to the begging of bitmap data
    fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bOffBits, SEEK_SET);

    //allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage);

    //verify memory allocation
    if (!bitmapImage)
    {
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
    }

    //read in the bitmap image data
    fread(bitmapImage, bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage, 1, filePtr);

    //make sure bitmap image data was read
    if (bitmapImage == NULL)
    {
        fclose(filePtr);
    }

    //swap the r and b values to get RGB (bitmap is BGR)
    for (imageIdx = 0;imageIdx < bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage;imageIdx+=3)
    {
        tempRGB = bitmapImage[imageIdx];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx] = bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2];
        bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2] = tempRGB;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, why are you calling `free (...)` when `bitmapImage` is **0**? The C stdlib is smart enough not to do anything if you try this, but it still makes no sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure

Comment: i have used the code written in here @AndonM.Coleman

Comment: If I remove the free part then it gives me a segmentation error;

Comment: What OS is this on? Why are you trying to read a BMP manually? There are OS routines for reading in most image formats. You shouldn't write this code yourself. Also, this has nothing to do with OpenGL or C++, so I'm going to remove those tags.

Comment: I am using linux mint. what am I supposed to do?

Comment: can you atleast point me to the right direction?

Comment: Yeah... do not do that. There are too many really bad things in that code, like freeing a pointer that has the value **0** immediately after checking to see if its value is **0** (this is safe, but completely pointless). But more importantly, it needs to `return` on failure after calling `fclose (...)`; that code is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Since when does C++ have `fread (...)`, `free (...)`, etc? This is a mishmash of C++ and the C standard library. And as it turns out, all of the bad things that are happening in this code are a result of misusing the C standard library.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: C++ has always had those things. C has never had namespaces or the `new` operator, and fails to have them to this day.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: No, those things (`fread`, `free`, etc.) are part of the C standard library, not C++. Heck, they are technically not even a part of the C language if you want to get nitpicky.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I'm not going to get into pointless arguments about whether C or C++ include their respective standard libraries. To the extent the language is defined by the standard, they are included, and that's good enough for me. And the C standard library, at least the bit that contains these here functions, is included in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This code that you got from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure) on StackOverflow has some awkward issues.

1. It checks to see if `bitmapImage` is **0** and if it is, it immediately calls `free (...)` on `bitmapImage`
2. It needs to ***return*** on failure in order to prevent crashing.
3. `fread (...)` does not change whether or not `bitmapImage` is `NULL`

#### Here are some minimum changes that you need to make:

```c
if (filePtr == NULL) {
    cout << "ERROR!!! 1" << endl;
    return -1; // FAILURE, so return!
}

[...]

//allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage);

//verify memory allocation
if (!bitmapImage)
{
    //free(bitmapImage); // This does not belong here!
    fclose(filePtr);
    return -2; // FAILURE, so return!
}

//read in the bitmap image data
fread(bitmapImage, bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage, 1, filePtr);

// THIS IS POINTLESS TOO, fread (...) is not going to change the address of
//                          bitmapImage.
/*
//make sure bitmap image data was read
if (bitmapImage == NULL)
{
    fclose(filePtr);
}
*/

//swap the r and b values to get RGB (bitmap is BGR)
for (imageIdx = 0;imageIdx < bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage;imageIdx+=3)
{
    tempRGB = bitmapImage[imageIdx];
    bitmapImage[imageIdx] = bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2];
    bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2] = tempRGB;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But how am I going to get a value for bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage this variable. initially it is 0. so it is not reading anything and it is not entering the loop.

Comment: Well, I honestly do not see why you are allocating  `BITMAPINFOHEADER` dynamically in this code. You never bother to free it before the program returns. Just declare it like you do `BITMAPFILEHEADER` and pass the address of the variable to `fread (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you should not be writing your own code to read in a .bmp file (unless it's for an assignment, or something like that). You say you're on mint linux, so you might try either [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). The code you're using doesn't handle index color images, for example, and probably a host of other things.

Answer (score 0):

that's how I load a BMP file of 24 bits per pixel, not for indexed colour bitmaps, download winbgim from here:  http://www.mediafire.com/file/z9wnl0c70tiacqn/winbgim_DevCpp.zip/file, is in dev-c++, you probably have to load a couple of parameters for the linker, the path is: project, project options, parameters, and write: -lbgi -lgdi32 -luser32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -mwindows -lwinmm, one thing more, after installing winbgim, go to  dev c and create new project as console graphics application, this item must be in the project list if winbgim is properly installed, 
I wrote "write to shared memory", because I wrote the file also in memory although I did not access the file this way, but from the same file

```
 #include <winbgim.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include<windows.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 const char *Filename;

 BITMAPFILEHEADER FileHeader;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER InfoHeader;
 int k;
 typedef struct{
 BYTE colorr;
 BYTE colorg;
 BYTE colorb;
 }cine;

 cine color;

 HANDLE hArch, hProy;
 LPSTR base,puntero;
 DWORD tam;
 int main()
 {
 int gdriver=9;
 int gmode=2;
 // initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode, "");
 cleardevice();

 UnmapViewOfFile(base);
 CloseHandle(hProy);
 CloseHandle(hArch);
 char *p;
 char *base;
 DWORD buf;
 Filename="D:\\music\\IMSLP00795-BWV0971\\01.bmp";
 int gd = DETECT, gm;
 int x = 320, y = 240, radius;
 k=0;

 int i;
 int j;




 FILE *File=NULL;
 if(!Filename)
 {
 MessageBox(NULL,"Konnte Filename nicht  finden!","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
 }
 else
 {
 File=fopen("D:\\music\\IMSLP00795-BWV0971\\01.bmp","rb");
 }

 fread(&FileHeader,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,File);
 if(FileHeader.bfType != 0x4D42)
 {
 MessageBox(NULL,"Ungültiges Bildformat!","Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
 exit(1); 
 }
 printf("tamaño total del archivo %d\n",FileHeader.bfSize);
 printf("comienzo del mapa de bits (imagen en pixels) en bits         %d\n",FileHeader.bfOffBits);

 buf=FileHeader.bfOffBits/8; //offset from the begining of BMP file (pixel array)
 printf("comienzo del mapa de bits en bytes desde el origen del archivo      %d\n",buf);
 fread(&InfoHeader,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,File);

 printf("horizontal resolution in pixels por metro %li\n",InfoHeader.biWidth);
 printf("vertical resolution in pixels por metro %li\n",InfoHeader.biHeight);
 printf("numero de bits por pixel %d", InfoHeader.biBitCount);
 initwindow(InfoHeader.biWidth,InfoHeader.biHeight);


 hArch = CreateFile("D:\\music\\IMSLP00795-BWV0971\\01.bmp", /* file  name */
 GENERIC_ALL , /* read/write access */
 0, /* no sharing of the file */
 NULL, /* default security */
 OPEN_ALWAYS, /* open new or existing file */
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, /* routine file attributes */
 NULL); /* no file template */
 if (hArch==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

 fprintf(stderr,"no puede abrirse el archivo");

 }

 hProy = CreateFileMapping(hArch, /* file handle */
 NULL, /* default security */
 PAGE_READWRITE, /* read/write access to mapped pages */
 0, /* map entire file */
 0,
 TEXT("SharedObject")); /* named shared memory object */

 /* write to shared memory */
 base=(LPSTR)MapViewOfFile(hProy,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,0);
 tam=GetFileSize(hArch,NULL);
 int cont=0;
 puntero=base;
 p=base+FileHeader.bfOffBits;
 k=0;int t=0,v,l;
 fseek(File,FileHeader.bfOffBits,SEEK_SET );
 int read=0,read2=0;
 k=0;
 for( i=0; i<InfoHeader.biWidth; i++ ) {
       fread(&color,sizeof(cine),1,File);
        read += sizeof(cine);
        printf( "Pixel %d: %3d %3d %3d\n", i+1, int(color.colorb),         int(color.colorg), int(color.colorr) );
    }
    if( read % 4 != 0 ) {
        read2 = 4 - (read%4);
        printf( "Padding: %d bytes\n", read2 );
        //fread( &color, read2, 1, File );

    }
    fseek(File,FileHeader.bfOffBits,SEEK_SET );
    for (i=0;i<InfoHeader.biHeight;i++)
 for(j=0;j<InfoHeader.biWidth ;j++)

{
 fread(&color,sizeof(cine),1,File);

 putpixel(j,InfoHeader.biHeight-  i,COLOR(int(color.colorb),int(color.colorg),int(color.colorr)));
 if(j==InfoHeader.biWidth-1&&read2!=0)fseek(File,read2,SEEK_CUR);
} 
 fclose(File);

 UnmapViewOfFile(base);
 CloseHandle(hProy);
 CloseHandle(hArch);
 getch();
}
```